# GeckoWebBrowser isn't showing (Handle) (C# WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, browser, gecko

I want to use the geckoWebBrowser but it says I have to assign the handle to something to display.
After searching a bit, a good solution seems to be to assign it to a tab page,especially to simulate multiple tabs, what I want to do.
But I don't know how it works. Assigning the parent of the browser to the tab page does nothing. I can't find almost anything about creating the handle when searching on google.

Can somebody give me some help please?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I had to call CreateControl() and then assigning the tab as parent really worked.